# Unable to debug radio buttons being unchecked randomly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Kindly see: https://jsfiddle.net/chrzrdx/krrczkx5/

This is on `vue 2.1.4`

I have a questions array in my vue.data, and I'm cycling through them every time the next or prev button is pressed. I store the `id` of the active question, and compute the active question from there. I am using `v-model` on the radio button to store the state in the active question's `selected` property.

The questions already have a default value (`selected` initially contains the value of the default option). But some radio buttons display as unchecked even though the `selected` field of the current (active) question is set.

The issue persists even if there are no default values in `selected`, and the user clicks each button herself.

Comment: all your checkboxes have the same name and all have the property "checked"  so last one loaded wins.  if more than one can be checked, use checkboxes

Comment: I'm using the v-bind shortcut to bind the name and value attributes of each radio button. The name is the same for the two options of each question, so that only one of them can be selected. Also, the radio buttons generated by each have their name set to the question's `id`.

Comment: oooh, I see what you mean.  hmmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove this `v-bind:name="active_question.txt"` from `input` tag in HTML, so following will be updated line.

```
<input type="radio" v-bind:value="o.txt" v-model="active_question.selected">
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/krrczkx5/9/

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. any reason why binding the name resulted in buggy behaviour? Aren't radio button elements (in a logical group) supposed to have the same name?

Comment: For those not paying attention like me, removing the `name` attribute is what fixed this for me. It'd be nice to learn why, but I am guessing it has something to do with `v-model` controlling the radio group.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer mentioned above, please see this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4375